# How can i seperate two types of users in firebase to seperate the login of web and mobile app users

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a project where the parking lot owners should use website login and other users should use mobile app login.
But currently any user can login into both of the website and mobile app.

here is my firebase realtime database
[my realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA8Kf.png)

So as you can see I defined type in user. when signing up a user gets a type depending on the device he/she registering

and my web sign in function is like this:

```
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;

    alert('User Logged in!');
    window.location = 'user.html';
}).catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

How can I provide login for the users which have 'type = web' ?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication only cares about credentials: if the email/password you enter matches the data in the system, you can sign in - no matter what platform you're on. There is no way to change this in Firebase Authentication, so any additional logic will have to come from your application code.

For example, you could store a list of the UIDs of the parking lot owners, and check against that after signing in to allow then to use the web app or not.

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
  const user = userCredential.user;

  if (user) {
    const uid = user.uid;                                  // determine the UID of the user
    const ownersRef = firebase.database().ref("parkinglotOwners");
    const userSnapshot = await ownersRef.child(uid).get(); // try to load this users data from parkinglotOwners
    if (userSnapshot.exists()) {                           // if this data exists
      window.location = 'user.html';                       // send them to the web app
    } else {
      alert("You're not allowed to use this app";          // tell them to go away
    }
  }

  ...
}).catch((error) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth is about authentication (are you the person you said you are).

Your need is more about Access Control.  There is a feature in Firebase that may help with that.  It's called "custom claims" and allow you to perform Claim-Based Access control.

see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32394743)